# Why doesn't the second for loop execute?

Tags: c, for-loop

printf debugging.  The while loop executes, the 1st for loop executes, the 2nd for loop does not.

```
while (size > 0){
    printf("in the while loop!\n");
    VertexPointer current = graph[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++){
        float dist = 0;
        printf("in the first for loop for i = %d \n", i);
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j++; j < dimension){
            printf("dist loop: %d\n", j);
            printf("current: %f\n", (*current).loc[0]);
            printf("unvisited: %f\n", (*graph[j]).loc[0]);

            dist = dist + pow((*current).loc[0] + (*graph[j]).loc[0], 2);
            printf("distance:  %f", dist);


            dist = sqrt(dist);
            if (dist < (*graph[i]).key){
                decreaseKey(graph, i, dist);
            }
        }

    }

    extractMin(graph, size);
    size = size - 1;
    mst_length = mst_length + (*current).key;
}
```

Comment: You switched the condition and increment: `j++; j < dimension` should be: `j < dimension; j++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switched the condition and increment:

```
for(j = 0; j++; j < dimension)
```

so the loop tests the value of `j++`, and since the postfix `++` operator returns the **previous** value of the variable it increments, it will return 0 (the initial value of `j`) on the first iteration and thus never loop. Change it to

```
for(j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
```

If you turn on warnings you should receive a message that the third expression has no side-effects (and would be optimized-away by the compiler).

---

Alternatively (**stop: don't actually do this**):

change the condition to `++j` to make it a (potentially) never-ending loop instead:

```
for(j = 0; ++j; j < dimension)
```

if you're lucky (which is usually, in this case) the loop will end when `j` reaches `MAX_INT` and wraps around to 0. But the standard doesn't guarantee that, so it's potentially endless.

Comment: Aside from the result of integer overflow being undefined by the standard (in contrary to unsigned overflow), still, in most implementations, it will wrap from `INT_MAX` to `INT_MIN`, not to 0.

Comment: Which is why I said you'll usually be lucky, but no guarantees.